# RequireJS configuration error - jQuery not found when calling Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I'm trying to setup a require js project for learning purposes. I need to run a Backbone app.

Index.html, looks plain and simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <title>RequireJS - Test drive</title>
    <!-- data-main attribute tells require.js to load scripts/main.js after 
require.js loads. -->
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/vendor/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>RequireJS - Test drive</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently I have this config in my main.js: (which is the entry point in index.html for requirejs)

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        underscore: 'vendor/underscore-1.9.1.min',
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min',
        backbone: 'vendor/backbone-1.4.0.min',
        app: 'app/app',
        userModel: 'app/models/user.model',
        userListView: 'app/views/user-list.view',
        userSingleView: 'app/views/user-single.view',
    },
    bundles: {
        'models': ['userModel']
    },
    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        }
    },
});

// Start the app
define(['app'], (App) => {
    return App.initialize();
});
```

In app.js, which I try to initiate the app with, I have the following:

```
define(['backbone'], (Backbone) => {

    const initialize = () => {
        console.log('App initialized.', Backbone);
        const data = {title: 'title'};
        const view = 0; // new View here....
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    }
});
```

Now, if I remove backbone as a dependency, I am able to see the console.log message in the browser. If I leave it there, then the console throws this error:

```
require.js:5 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/js/vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not 
Found)

require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Script error for "js/vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min", needed by: backbone
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
at makeError (require.js:5)
at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:5)
```

Inspecting the network tab, I can see that the jQuery dependency has errored out, and for some reason an additional /js has been added to the path, which results in a 404 error for jQuery, but only when I try to use Backbone on the app.js file.

Path looks like this, with the additional /js added to it:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/js/vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min.js
```

What is it that I am missing in the configuration/setup of the application?

Comment: What if you change `vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min` to `./vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should set [`baseUrl`](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl) in your config

```js
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/js'
});
```